# Properties of the element $2 \otimes_{R} x - x \otimes_{R} 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products

I'm doing this exercise from Dummit-Foote:

> Let $I = (2, x)$ be the ideal generated by $2$ and $x$ in the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]$.
>   Show that the nonzero element $2 \otimes_{R} x - x  \otimes_{R} 2$ in $I \otimes_{R} I$ is a torsion element. 
>   Show infact that $2 \otimes_{R} x - x  \otimes_{R} 2$ is annihilated by both $2$ and $x$ and that the submodule of $I \otimes_{R} I$ generated by $2 \otimes_{R} x - x  \otimes_{R} 2$ is isomorphic to $R/ I$.

I have proved that $2 \otimes_{R} x - x  \otimes_{R} 2 \neq 0$, it is annhilated by $2$ and $x$.

My question is: if $$q \in R \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ q \cdot ( 2 \otimes_{R} x - x  \otimes_{R} 2 ) = 0$$

why $ q \in I = (2, x) $ ?

Comment: How many elements does $\mathbb Z[x]/(2,x)$ have?

Comment: One question: how did you prove $\;2\otimes x-x\otimes 2\neq0\;\;\text{in}\;\;I\otimes I\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio: it is explained in the previous exercises of the book, pag. $376 - 377 $

Comment: Why would *anyone* downvote such an interesting, non-trivial question as this one, in particular when the OP already did some rather long work on it, is beyond my comprehension...and patience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, it should be clear that since $2$ and $x$ annihilate $2\otimes x - x \otimes 2$, then clearly all of $I$ annihilates $2\otimes x - x \otimes 2$. Moreover, the set of elements which annihilate $2\otimes x - x \otimes 2$ is clearly an ideal of $R$.

Now, consider $R/I$. The way to think about this is that we are basically killing everything in $R$ which is a multiple of $x$ or a multiple of $2$. The only things left are $0$ and $1$! Hence, $I$ is a maximal ideal of $R$. Since $2\otimes x - x \otimes 2 \neq 0$, the annihilator ideal cannot be all of $R$, so the only option is that it is actually $I$ itself.

Comment: Very nice answer. +1