# Show that $x\otimes x+2\otimes2$ is not an elementary tensor in $I\otimes_{A}I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

> Let $A=\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $I=(2,x)\lhd A.$ Show that $x\otimes x+2\otimes2$ is not an elementary tensor in $I\otimes_{A}I$.

I have
$$I\otimes_A I = \frac{L_A(I\times I)}{T}$$

where $T$ is the submodule generated by the elementary tensors $$\{(am,n)-a(m,n);(m,an)-a(m,n);(m,n)+(m,n')-(m,n+n');(m,n)+(m',n)-(m+m',n)\}$$

I haven't been able to to much work here. I have a couple of ideas: showing that $x\otimes x+2\otimes2$ can't be written in one of the form above to prove is not elementary. A possible alternative would show that the tensor given is can be written as a linaer combination of elementary tensors (and is this always true? question arise because not every tensor consists only of elementary tensors).

Comment: I think this problem has a guided solution in Dummit and Foote.

Comment: This has been asked before: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823642/2-otimes-r-2-x-otimes-r-x-is-not-a-simple-tensor-in-i-otimes-r-i?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints in steps:

- The map $\;\varphi: I\times I\to A\;,\;\;\varphi(r,s):=rs\;$ is bilinear, so we get a unique homomorphism $\;\phi: I\otimes I\to A\;$ .
- Assume $\; 2\otimes 2+ x\otimes x= r\otimes s\;$ . Prove that then $\;4 + x^2=rs\;$ .
- Reach a contradiction by analyzing the (two) differentpossibilites of $\;r,s\;$: or $\;\deg r=0\;$ or $\;r=x^2+2a\;,\;\;s=x^2+2b\;,\;\;a,b\in\Bbb Z\;$ .