# If $R$-modules $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic free modules, is $M \otimes_R M$ isomorphic to $N \otimes_R N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, free-modules

Given a commutative ring $R$ and two isomorphic free $(R,R)$-bimodules $M$ and $N$, is it true that the tensor product $M\otimes_R M$ is isomorphic to the tensor product $N \otimes_R N$?

Here's my idea thus far: Given an $R$-module isomorphism $\varphi:M\rightarrow N$, we know there is a unique $R$-module homomorphism $\Phi=(\varphi\otimes\varphi):M\otimes_R M\rightarrow N\otimes_R N$ given by $\Phi(m_1\otimes m_2)=\varphi(m_1)\otimes\varphi(m_2)$. Clearly this map is surjective, given the surjectivity of $\varphi$, but I'm struggling to determine if it's injective. I know the kernel of $\Phi$ is given by the elements $m_1\otimes m_2 \in M\otimes_R M$ such that $\varphi(m_1)\otimes\varphi(m_2)=0$, but is it possible to then determine that $m_1\otimes m_2=0$?

Comment: An element of the kernel is not necessary of the form $m_1\otimes m_2$. Not every element in the tensor product is a simple tensor. In general, showing a map defined on a tensor product is injective is usually not so easy. Instead of that, you can easily define an inverse map.

Comment: @Mark thanks for the reply! Do you have an example of an element in the tensor product that isn't a simple tensor? I'm still new to all of this.

Comment: There are many examples. Here is one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823642/2-otimes-r-2-x-otimes-r-x-is-not-a-simple-tensor-in-i-otimes-r-i

Comment: If $M_1 \stackrel {\varphi_1} \longrightarrow N_1 \stackrel {\psi_1} \longrightarrow L_1$ and $M_2 \stackrel {\varphi_2} \longrightarrow N_2 \stackrel {\psi_2} \longrightarrow L_2$, then $$(\psi_1 \otimes \psi_2) \circ (\varphi_1 \otimes \varphi_2) = (\psi_1 \circ \varphi_1) \otimes (\psi_2 \circ \varphi_2).$$ Use this and the fact that $\varphi$ has an inverse to show that $\Phi$ is has an inverse too. *Note*: Freeness is no needed for this problem.

Comment: You can use the fact that $$\ker(\varphi\otimes\varphi)=\ker\varphi\otimes M+M\otimes\ker\varphi$$.